# Tame Impala/Kevin Parker Vocal recording

Tags: pro-tools, reverb, vocals, delay

I really like the vocal recording on Tame Impala's debut album Innerspeaker

I'm trying  to achieve a similar result.

I know that it involves double tracking, delays and reverbs, but I wish someone could have told me EXACTLY what to do (types of reverbs and delays to use, what kind of automation I should apply, the spacial EQ for the double vocals, etc.).
 I have been trying to do it alone for months, but I got very mediocre results, and I was hoping maybe you guys (and gals) could help me with it.

Comment: Adding a timestamp to your youtube link might help - no-one's going to listen to an hour of it to figure out which bit you mean.

Comment: Check out this video on ADT http://www.waves.com/plugins/reel-adt#butch-vig-billy-bush-reel-adt

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely a real Space Echo (RE-201 / RE-301) and not some plugin chain. We have one in the studio and use it for exactly such things. Those tape delay devices are very tough to imitate using software.

The exact same question has been [discussed at Gearslutz](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/newbie-audio-engineering-production-question-zone/777716-tame-impala-vocal-effect.html) - [one reply](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/8503954-post10.html) states that Kevin is using the RE-20 Space Echo (the pedal version) along with some special EQ'ing.

The Space Echo will deliver the harsh gain, reverb and echo effects along with some tape-speed pitch flutter, which besides the EQ and panning tricks seem to be what that sound is about.

Comment: Double tracking your voice too, which is what Lennon did in later day Beatles stuff

Comment: I like michaels answer, but i think he missed the Dolby A trick (https://www.gearslutz.com/board/low-end-theory/39728-dolby-unit-tricks-vocals.html)

There's the distinct whisper which can't really be produced by eqing.. especially a signal passed from the space echo!